# Pause slider when embedded Dailymotion video is started

Tags: javascript, jquery, dailymotion-api

I have a slider (flexslider) with a daylimotion video in each slide. The slider runs automatically, the videos do not. So far the videos are embedded as iFrames, but I can switch them to the Web SDK API if necessary.

The slider can be paused in the following way:
`$('.flexslider').flexslider("pause");`

How can I create a listener that stops the slider as soon as any of the embedded videos is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Dailymotion SDK docs](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player/#player-api-events-player) you can listen for the `start` event on the player and do something whenever the player has started, like stopping your carousel from running.

Here's an example for a single video which stops the slider.

```
const player = DM.player(document.getElementById('player'), {
  video: 'xwr14q',
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',   
  params: {
    autoplay: true,
    mute: true
  }
});

player.addEventListener('start', function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider("pause");
});
```

This is not possible with just an iframe as you don't have a way to communicate to the player.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that does not require extra JavaScript to be added for each video:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js"></script>

<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><div class="dmplayer" data-video="x7tgad0"></div></li>
        <li><div class="dmplayer" data-video="x7tgad0"></div></li>
        <li><div class="dmplayer" data-video="x7tgad0"></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    
    $(".dmplayer").each(function(index, element){
        var $this = $(this);
        var video = $(this).data('video');
        var player = new DM.player(this,{ 
            video: video, 
            width: "100%", 
            height: "100%", 
        });
        player.addEventListener('start', function() {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider("pause");
        });
    });
    
});
```